# Why won't my accordion close all the way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making some accordion FAQ questions. When I add padding around the answer portion, my accordion won't close all the way. When I remove the padding, the accordion works fine. The problem is that I want the padding.

As stated before, my accordion works perfectly fine when padding is removed. When the padding is added back, the collapsed answer still shows the first few lines of text in the answer.

*(The accordion in question is the last entry on the page, headed with "0002.")*

```css
body {
  font-family: 'work sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #010101;
  background: url(https://imgur.com/YRl8KNP.png) fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: left;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #010101;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}

#header {
  padding: 160px;
}

.h_title {
  font: 150px 'work sans';
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.h_menu {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 175px;
}

.h_top {
  text-align: right;
  font: 12px 'work sans';
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.h_top::before {
  content: '////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////';
  font: 11px 'arial';
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  color: #ff00ff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.h_tabs input {
  display: none;
}

.h_tabs {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 230px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.h_tabs label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  font: 9px 'work sans';
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 90px;
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 160px;
}

.h_tabs label b {
  color: #ff00ff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.h_tabs label span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.h_tabs label:after {
  content: '001';
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  font-eight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.6s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(2):after {
  content: '002';
}

.h_tabs label:nth-of-type(3):after {
  content: '003';
}

.h_tabs input:checked+label span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.h_tabs input:checked+label::after {
  width: 0px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.h_tab1,
.h_tab2 {
  width: 700px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.h_blurb {
  font: 14px 'work sans';
  color: #ccc;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.h_cont {
  background: #171717;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.h_nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0px 35px 15px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 6px;
  font: 12px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #aaa;
}

.h_nav a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  background: #ff00ff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.h_nav a:nth-of-type(2n):after {
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.h_nav a:nth-of-type(3n):after {
  background: #ff00ff;
}

.h_nav a:hover:after {
  width: 180px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#htab1:checked~.h_tab1,
#htab2:checked~.h_tab2 {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

#lean_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/zdXP0Uo.jpg) fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
}

#Pages #wrapper {
  background: transparent;
}

#page_container {
  width: 1100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.page_menu {
  font: 12px 'share tech mono';
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.page_menu a:active {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.page_menu h1 {
  font: 17px 'work sans';
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.page_menu h1:before {
  content: '/ ';
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.page_content {
  background: #171717;
  width: 705px;
  float: left;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  outline-offset: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 150%;
}

.page_content h1 {
  font: 50px 'work sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.page_content h2 {
  font: 15px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.page_text {
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

.page_text u {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.page_em {
  margin: 30px;
  font: 10px 'share tech mono';
  line-height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 30px;
}

.page_em u {
  color: #ff00ff;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.page_menu ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.page_menu li ol {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.page_menu b {
  color: #ff00ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.page_menu ol li {
  display: block;
}

.page_menu li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.sub_canons li {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  font: 7px 'work sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sub_canons {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.sub_canons li b {
  display: block;
  font: 10px 'share tech mono';
}

.page_content h3 {
  font: 14px 'share tech mono';
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h3::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 12px;
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.page_content h4 {
  font: 13px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h4::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #ff1053;
}

.page_content h5 {
  font: 13px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h5::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #4592f7;
}

.page_content h6 {
  font: 13px 'share tech mono';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  counter-increment: faqcounter;
}

.page_content h6::before {
  content: '00' counter(faqcounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #ff5f32;
}


/* Tagging */

a.user-tagged.mgroup-4 {
  color: #744dba;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-8 {
  color: #ff1053;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-6 {
  color: #4592f7;
}

a.user-tagged.mgroup-7 {
  color: #ff5f32;
}

.iconpad {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.padex {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

::selection {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

faqentry {
  margin: 0px 20px 5px 20px;
  display: block;
}

faqentry ol li {
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #d8fe56;
}

div.toggle {
  margin: 10px 30px 20px 30px;
  padding: 40px;
  line-height: 170%!important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .accordion {
      font: 14px 'share tech mono';
      text-align: right;
      text-transform: lowercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      margin: 20px 0px;
      color: #fff;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    div.panel {
      margin: 10px 30px 20px 30px;
      padding: 40px;
      line-height: 170%;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      display: block;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="HERE">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,400,700,900|Share+Tech+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>STICTION</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="STICTION.css" TYPE="text/css">

</head>

<div id="header">
  <div class="h_title">stiction</div>
  <div class="h_menu">
    <div class="h_top"></div>
    <div class="h_tabs">

      <input id="htab1" type="radio" name="htabs" checked>
      <label for="htab1"><span>CANDY TEETH, NEON IDIOTS.</span> <b>/</b></label>

      <input id="htab2" type="radio" name="htabs">
      <label for="htab2"><span>OTHER LINKS</span> <b>/</b></label>

      <div class="h_tab1">
        <div class="h_blurb"><i>Welcome to the new world; myth meets the future. Where do you fit in?</i><br><br>
          <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family: share tech mono; font-size: 11px;">literate supernatural and cyberpunk group roleplay set in City 0215 during the year 2447.</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="h_tab2">
        <div class="h_nav">
          <a href="https://discord.gg/2Rrw9QB">DISCORD</a>
          <a href="http://GOOGLELINKHERE.com">DIRECTORY</a>
          <a href="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/1euBOWkTE7hnMCsPgBFlqM">PLAYLIST</a>


        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="page_container">


    <div class="page_menu">
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">INDEX</a></li>
      </ol>
      <h1>ESSENTIAL READS</h1>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">QUICK-START GUIDE</a></li>
        <span style="color: #ff00ff; font-weight: bold;">RULES</span>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">HISTORY</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SETTING</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://idiots.jcink.net/index.php?act=Pages&pid=5">SPECIES</a></li>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">LIVING</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">DECEASED</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">PRUGATORIC</a></li>
        </ol>
      </ol>
      <h1>IN-DEPTH CONTENT</h1>
      <ol>

        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOTS</a></li>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOT 001</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOT 002</a></li>
          <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">SUBPLOT 003</a></li>
        </ol>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">OFFICIAL SERVER FACTIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PAGETITLE.html">MEMBER-CREATED FACTIONS</a></li>

      </ol>
    </div>

    <div class="page_content">

      <div class="page_text" id="top">
        <h1>lore questions</h1>


        <div class="page_em"><u>A NOTE</u> This world- the world of <u style="color: #4fecc8; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 7px; font-family: 'work sans', Arial, sans-serif;">STICTION</u>- isn't just the project and product of
          the staff team. We want you to feel that you can contribute to this world! To that end, these are all questions that guests and members have asked in our Discord. Questions are either answered according to existing lore, or (in cases where the
          staff team hasn't thought of a situation or scenario) are talked out with members to come to a satisfying answer. This page is updated regularly, so make sure you keep an eye on it!
          <p>

            It's probably easiest to explore this page using the <b>CRTL+F</b> function, especially if you have specific questions!</div>

        <h2>quick links</h2>
        <faqentry id="quick links">
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#section"><u>world-building</u></a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2"><u>subplots</u></a></li>
            <ol>
              <li><a href="#wires"><u>crossed wires subplot</u></a></li>
              <li><a href="#applause"><u>live for the applause subplot</u></a></li>
              <li><a href="#blood"><u>blood and chocolate subplot</u></a></li>
            </ol>

            <li><a href="#section3"><u>species-specific</u></a>
              <ol>
                <li><a href="#abilities"><u>general abilities</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#witches"><u>witches</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#shifters"><u>shifters</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#vampires"><u>vampires</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#reapers"><u>reapers</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#ghosts"><u>ghosts</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#phoenixes"><u>phoenixes</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#familiars"><u>familiars</u></a></li>
                <li><a href="#androids"><u>androids</u></a></li>
              </ol>
          </ol>
        </faqentry>


        <a name="section">&nbsp;</a>
        <Br><br>
        <h2>world-building</h2>

        <h3>context clues</h3>
        Before you get started exploring this new world, it’s helpful to keep in mind a few things for context! (It might even help you answer your own questions, who knows?) The first bit of info you’ll need is that electricity and all other forms of energy
        are obsolete; instead, the world runs on magic energy. That leads into point two, which is that supernatural, magic creatures are no longer monsters under the bed, or creatures in the shadow; they live open, public lives.<br><br> Since
        this is a cyberpunk site, it stands to reason that technology is wildly more advanced than what we have now. It’s no so advanced that interstellar travel exists, but it’s so much farther ahead that paper (and privacy, in a lot of ways) is a thing
        of the past. Every person on the planet is in some way connected to the Global Communications Lattice (or GCL) for short, and everything on the planet runs through it. As far as specific pieces of technology go, that’s largely up to you, your
        ideas, and genre standards.<br>
        <Br> It never hurts to ask an admin or run an idea by us before executing an idea, though!

        <button class="accordion"><h3>What's the primary language spoken in City 0023? What about the rest of the world?</h3></button>
        <div class="panel">English has become the primary language of most of the world, but thanks to the ease of information access, every language (even dead languages) can be learned now! Linguistic diversity not only still exists in this world, but is flourishing;
          most people can claim some form of bilingualism. English, French, and Chinese are the top three languages spoken in City 0023.</div>

        <br>
        <Br>
        <a href="#top"><u>Back to Top</u></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
          } else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: You have provided us with a lot of code that is actually irrelevant to the question at hand. Please condense your code to a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question, as you discovered, as long as that `.panel` div has top and bottom padding, it will have an intrinsic minimum height which is why it wasn't closing all the way.

The easiest way I can think of to achieve the desired result without changing too much of your existing code is to nest the text inside a div that is a child of `.panel` and move the padding property (and optionally the line-height property as well) to the nested element (which I called `.panel__content` -- you can call it whatever you want).

```css
div.panel {
  margin:10px 30px 20px 30px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  display:block;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.panel__content {
  padding:40px;
  line-height: 170%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel__content">English has become the primary language of most of the world, but thanks to the ease of information access, every language (even dead languages) can be learned now! Linguistic diversity not only still exists in this world, but is flourishing; most people can claim some form of bilingualism. English, French, and Chinese are the top three languages spoken in City 0023.</div>
</div>
```

Working [JSFidddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pvzk7wxt/)

---

**Some side notes:**

1. I would also highly recommend that you validate your HTML and CSS, as you have a number of validation errors currently. Best way to do that is to paste your code into W3C's online validators:

   - **HTML Validator:**
     https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
   - **CSS Validator:**
     https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input
2. You might not need to add `div` to your `.panel` selector to achieve the same result. All things being equal, it's a best practice to have selectors be as short as possible.
3. You might not need to set `.panel` to `display:block;` as div's have this property value by default.

Comment: Thank you! I’m fairly new to coding so I know my CSS is kind of a wreck; thank you for the help, honestly!

Comment: @jord You're welcome! I should also point out that my proposed change to move the line-height property to the nested div is optional. While it makes sense to me to have it at that level, it won't affect you achieving your desired functionality, so it's your call.

Comment: @jord also if you're satisfied with my answer, could you click the checkmark next to my post to officially accept the answer? I'm trying to earn more reputation, and this will help me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

On your panel. This should make it so the `padding` is a part of `height`. You may have to adjust other values if that shifts things slightly.
Otherwise, you could set padding top and bottom to 0 when closed and transition those values as well, when collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

max-height property overrides the height property but the padding top and bottom value will added to the height when css is getting compiled and value of height well be 80px

so set the padding to

```
div.panel { padding: 0 40px }
```

and change your script to

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      panel.style.paddingTop = 0;
      panel.style.paddingBottom = 0
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      panel.style.paddingTop = null;
      panel.style.paddingBottom = null
    } 
  })
}
```